A possible error in a math question of 2022 Brazil's ENEM, a equivalent to US's SAT
This is a rather simple question, and it may seem like a physics question, but it actually belongs to a math test. I'll translate it into English first and then reproduce the Portuguese version.
"The performance of a dual-fuel car (fueled with alcohol or gasoline), popularly known as a flex car, when fueled with alcohol is lower than when fueled with gasoline, according to the graph, which shows the average performance of popular cars.

Suppose a citizen took a trip, the distance of which was 1,009 km, in a popular flex-fuel car, having fueled the car for the first 559 km with gasoline and, for the remainder of the journey, with alcohol. Consider that at the time of refueling there was no more fuel in the tank.
What is the closest value to the car's average performance after completing the entire 1,009 km route?"
The answer to this question is said to be 10.84 km/L, but I think it should be above 11 km/L, more precisely 11.2 km/L, because a greater distance was travelled by gas, so the answer should be closer to 13 than to 9.

I found the following reasoning for the 10.84 answer:
"of the 1009 km we have 559 km with gasoline and 450 km with alcohol. According to the graph, gasoline is 13km/L and alcohol is 9km/L. So, how many liters will we use?
GASOLINE: 559/13 = 43L;
ALCOHOL: 450/9 = 50L;
43 + 50 = 93L;
Now just take the total km and total L --> 1009km/93L = 10.84km/L"

You didn't complete the question acutally. What's after "Consider that at the time of refueling there was no more fuel in the tank."

ok, now it is completed. Thank you.

Just to adress to your beginning remark : This is not a physical problem , but a purely mathematical problem. No physical theory is needed to solve it.

The given answer is totally Correct.
$\frac{559}{13}+\frac{1009-559}{9}=93$ total liters
$\frac{1009}{\frac{559}{13}+\frac{1009-559}{9}}=10.849462$ average mileage
Only Issue unresolved is your Observation that it must be closer to $13$ (Distance is more) than to $9$ (Distance is more) which seems weird here :
Partially valid : Here average mileage was not calculated by "arithmetic mean" , in which case your Observation must be true. Actually , average mileage was calculated by "harmonic mean" , in which case answer reciprocal ($\frac{1}{10.849462}=0.092170$) must be closer to $\frac{1}{13}=0.076923$ than to $\frac{1}{9}=0.111111$ which is indeed true !!

you mean $(1009-559)/9$?

Nice Catch , @IgorPaulino , I was a Copy Paste typo which I have corrected it now , thank you.

$\frac{55913+4509}{1009}=11.2$ Why cannot I take the average of the performances by the kilometer weighted by the kilometers run by each?

Would you claim that, if the car were to traverse 500 kilometers by gas and then 500 more by alcohol, then its average speed would be 10,6km/L and not 11km/L

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Examples , @IgorPaulino , that might make things clear. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when too later !

The average efficiency of the vehicle is given by
$$\text{average efficiency} = \frac{\text{total distance traveled}}{\text{total fuel used}}. $$
The numerator is simple enough:  the vehicle traveled $1009~\text{km}$.  The denominator is a bit more complicated.  Over the first $559~\text{dm}$ of the journey, when the vehicle was using gasoline, it was burning fuel at a rate of $ \frac{1~\text{L}}{13~\text{km}}$.
Thus the vehicle burned
$$ \frac{1~\text{L}}{13~\text{km}} \cdot 559~\text{km}
= \frac{559}{13}~\text{L}
= 43~\text{L}. $$
On the second leg of the journey, the vehicle was burning fuel at a rate of $ \frac{1~\text{L}}{9~\text{km}}$,
and so it burned
$$ \frac{1~\text{L}}{9~\text{km}} \cdot (1009-559)~\text{km}
= \frac{450}{9}~\text{L}
= 50~\text{L}. $$
Therefore the vehicle burned a total of
$$ (43 + 50)~\text{L} = 93~\text{L} $$
of fuel.
Plugging these into the original expression gives
$$\text{average efficiency}
= \frac{\text{total distance traveled}}{\text{total fuel used}}
= \frac{1009~\text{km}}{93~\text{L}}
\approx 10.85~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{L}}. $$
Note that the computed value, out to more decimal places, is $\approx 10.8494623656$, which should be rounded to $10.85$.  The answer (C) is the "most correct" answer from among those given (though I might argue that it isn't quite the answer which should be given).

NB:  The other answers are fine (though I feel that throwing around terms like "harmonic mean" and "arithmetic mean" kind of put the cart before the horse), but I think that they could be a little more pedagogical.  This answer is intended to explain (hopefully a little more clearly) how one might think about this problem.

Would you claim that, if the car were to traverse 500 kilometers by gas and then 500 more by alcohol, then its average speed would be 10,6km/L and not 11km/L ?

@IgorPaulino I don't know, because I have not worked through that problem.  But probably, yes.  Again, the average efficiency is (total distance) / (total fuel).

There is an analogous question regarding speed.
A car travels $50\ \text{km}$ at a speed of $100\ \text{km}/\text{hr}$
and then an additional $50\ \text{km}$ at a speed of $50\ \text{km}/\text{hr}.$
What is the average speed of this journey?
The answer is not $75\ \text{km}/\text{hr},$ even though the car spent exactly half the distance driving at each speed and $75\ \text{km}/\text{hr}$ is exactly halfway between the two speeds.
Instead, the answer is $66.67\ \text{km}/\text{hr},$ because the car traveled a total of $100\ \text{km}$ in $1.5\ \text{hr}.$

Whenever you ask, "what is the average $Y$ per $X,$"
the answer can always be obtained by taking the total amount of $Y$ and dividing by the total amount of $X.$
If you are given the total amount of $X$ in two portions, $X = X_1 + X_2,$
and you have the average "$Y$ per $X$" for both of those portions,
that is, you know $Y_1/X_1$ and $Y_2/X_2$ where $Y_1$ was the first portion of $Y$ and $Y_2$ is the second portion of $Y,$ then you can use a simple weighted arithmetic mean to find the average rate $Y/X$:
$$ \frac{\frac{Y_1}{X_1} \cdot X_1 + \frac{Y_2}{X_2} \cdot X_2}{X_1 + X_2}
= \frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{X_1 + X_2} = \frac YX.$$
In this arithmetic, if $X_1$ is larger than $X_2,$ the final average will come out closer to $Y_1/X_1$ than to $Y_2/X_2.$
But it is not always true that when $Y_1$ is larger than $Y_2,$ the final average will come out closer to $Y_1/X_1$ than to $Y_2/X_2.$
In the $\text{km}/\text{hr}$ example I gave earlier, $Y$ is the total kilometers traveled and $X$ is the total hours. The fact that the number of kilometers is the same in each part of the trip does not mean the final answer is exactly midway between the given speeds. The final answer is closer to the speed for the part of the trip that took more hours.
In your problem, the overall performance (total kilometers per liter) is closer to the performance for the part of the trip in which more liters were consumed, not the part of the trip that covered more kilometers.
The calculation would be much more intuitive if we measured performance in the European way, as liters per $100$ kilometers. Then we have the following performance figures:

Using gasoline: $7.692$ liters per $100$ kilometers.
Using alcohol: $11.11$ liters per $100$ kilometers.

The number of $100$-kilometer units of distance in each part of the journey are $5.59$ and $4.5$ respectively, so we have the average
$$ \frac{7.692 \cdot 5.59 + 11.11 \cdot 4.5}{5.59 + 4.5} \approx 9.216,  $$
which is closer to $7.692$ than to $11.11$ because the car traveled a longer distance at the lower rate of fuel/distance.
Now, $9.216$ liters per $100$ kilometers means we get an average of
$\frac{100}{9.216} \approx 10.85$ kilometers per liter of fuel.
Again, when you measure performance in kilometers per liter, the overall performance of the car on a trip is dominated by the part of the trip that consumed more liters, not the part that covered more kilometers.

would you claim that, if a car were to traverse 1000 kilometers at 2km/L and then 2km more at 1000km/L, then its average performance would be smaller than 2km/L, namely, approximately, $\frac{1002}{\frac{2}{1000}+\frac{1000}{2}}=1/2km/L$, and not greater than 2km/L, namely, 4 km/L, approximately?

@IgorPaulino Of course not, because $\frac{1002}{\frac{2}{1000}+\frac{1000}{2}} \approx 2.004,$ which is, in fact, greater than $2$ and is the correct answer. How can you get $4$ km/L when you have already burned $500$ liters in the first $1000$ kilometers?

yeah, I have calculated it wrong, but why is it 2km/L and not 4km/L?

It's not exactly $2$ km/L but is close to $2$ km/L because you only went $1002$ km and yet you burned over $500$ liters of fuel.

Would you claim that, if the car were to traverse 500 kilometers by gas and then 500 more by alcohol, then its average speed would be 10,6km/L and not 11km/L ?

If you have one of those cars that tracks km/L on each trip and gives you the result in real time, you may notice that if you are stopped at a red light for a long time but the engine is still running. the km/L readout on your dashboard can actually decrease during that time. How can that be? You are not traveling any distance, so if the distance traveled is what you average over, the performance while you are stopped should not count at all.

Have you actually read my answer? Did you understand why $50$ km at $100$ km/hour and $50$ km at $50$ km/hour is not an average speed of $75$ km/hour? Your last comment suggests you have not or did not.

$$\frac{559*13+450*9}{1009}=11.2$$
The average to be used is the weighted, and not the harmonic, if one is to follow the following reasoning:
if a car were to traverse $500$ kilometers by gas and then $500$ more by alcohol, then its average performance would be $11\ km/L$, and not $10.6\ km/L$, but
$$\frac{1000}{\frac{500}{13}+\frac{500}{9}}=10.6\ km/L$$
